# Cannot convert int to string in Java

Tags: java, string, char

I get an error: `cannot convert int to string in Java`

Script simply extracts a 'hidden' word inside a string by taking the first 2 letters, mid letter and last 2 letters

Here's my code:

```
package hello;
import java.util.*;
public class hello {
    public static String extract(String input) {
        if (input.length()>5) {
            int len = input.length();
            return input.charAt(0) + input.charAt(1) + input.charAt(len/2)+ input.charAt(len-2)+ input.charAt(len-1);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a word:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        String output = extract(input);
        System.out.println(output);     
    }
}
```

Comment: `char` is an integer type. If you add together a bunch of characters, you get an int, not a string.

Answer (score 3):

```
return input.charAt(0) + input.charAt(1) + input.charAt(len/2)+ input.charAt(len-2)+ input.charAt(len-1)
```

`char` is an int type. If you add together a bunch of characters, you get an int, not a string.

On the other hand, if you add a string to a char, or to another string, then they are concatenated into another string:

```
return input.substring(0,2) + input.charAt(len/2) + input.substring(len-2);
```

*Edit*

Your method currently only returns if `input.length()>5`. If the length is 5 or less, your method doesn't know what it should return, so the code will not compile.

If you know what your method should return in this case, add an extra `return` after your `if` block.

```
public static String extract(String input) {
    int len = input.length();
    if (len >= 5) {
        return input.substring(0,2) + input.charAt(len/2) + input.substring(len-2);
    }
    return input; // must return something if the length was less than 5.
}
```

Alternatively, you might want to throw an exception if your string is too short.

Answer (score 2):

When you use + between two chars it considered like you sum two integer for example :

```
'a' + 'b'
```

Is equivalent to :

```
97 + 98
```

In your case you can use `String.copyValueOf` to create a String from your chars.

```
return String.copyValueOf(new 
        char[] { 
                input.charAt(0), input.charAt(1), input.charAt(len / 2),
                input.charAt(len - 2), input.charAt(len - 1) 
        }
);
```

This will create a String from this chars.

Your method still need to return a default value if your condition is not correct.

```
public static String extract(String input) {
    if (input.length() > 5) {
        int len = input.length();
        return String.copyValueOf(new 
                char[] { 
                        input.charAt(0), input.charAt(1), input.charAt(len / 2),
                        input.charAt(len - 2), input.charAt(len - 1) 
                }
        );
    }
    return "";//if the condition is wrong return empty string or null
}
```